# asp.net Session is available only in certain pages and not all for a project

Tags: asp.net, session, module

For some reason, I have HttpContext.Current.Session available only in certain pages. But when I make runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests as true now it is also available in all pages. I don't want to turn it on for performance reason.
I m wondering what config or other setting causing session to be available only in certain pages. 
I also made sure that EnableSessionState="true" is true in all pages.